# Algebraic independence of the values of algebraic functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$A_1,...,A_n$ be explicitly given functions $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

1.) How can be checked if for each $x_0\in D\ \ A_1(x_0),...,A_n(x_0)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$?

2.) How can the $x_0$ be determined for which $A_1(x_0),...,A_n(x_0)$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$?

I tried the Wronskian determinant, but it seems to work only for linear independence over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

I already found:

If $A_1,...,A_n$ all are rational functions over $\mathbb{Q}$, $A_1(x_0),...,A_n(x_0)$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$ for all rational $x_0\in D$. That means, to be linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ for rational $x_0\in D$, one or more of $A_1,...,A_n$ must contain at least one irrational coefficient or are irrational functions.

I could build all combinations of up to three elements of $\{A_1,...,A_n\}$ and check if they are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$ because for up to 3 elements, I need to calculate only one coefficient of the linear combination and check if it is rational. But what is with larger matrices?

In [How can the row rank of a matrix with complex elements be calculated over $\mathbb{Q}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3379623/how-can-the-row-rank-of-a-matrix-with-complex-elements-be-calculated-over-math?noredirect=1#comment6955797_3379623), I asked for detailed algorithms for question 1).

Comment: Your question has several problems. You meant the $A_j$ are algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}(x)$ ? To make functions from them you need to choose some branches. Also is $x_0$ rational, algebraic or transcendental ? Then $\Bbb{Q}(A_1(x_0,\ldots,A_n(x_0),x_0)/\Bbb{Q}(x_0)$ is a finite extension so the first thing to do is to find its defining minimal polynomials (from the minimal polynomials of the $A_j$), from there the $\Bbb{Q}(x_0)$-linear relations between them can be found as well as the $\Bbb{Q}$ linear relations (if they exist).

Comment: For $x_0$ transcendental, when the chosen branches of the $A_j$ are analytic, the $\Bbb{Q}(x_0)$ algebraic and linear relations between the $A_j(x_0)$ won't depend on $x_0$.